# How to create worker cert for Coreos kubernetes aws cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, coreos

Ok, So I am defiantly not a security expert and battling with this for a few days now,

I am using the Coreos `kube-aws` cloud-formation template maker, and i want to deploy my cluster to production but because of this little comment:

> PRODUCTION NOTE: the TLS keys and certificates generated by kube-aws should not be used to deploy a production Kubernetes cluster. Each component certificate is only valid for 90 days, while the CA is valid for 365 days. If deploying a production Kubernetes cluster, consider establishing PKI independently of this tool first

I need to generate my own keys, but I don't seem to understand how to do that, their documentation (IMHO as someone who's not an expert) is seriously outrageous if you are not a familiar with.

**So my requirements are like so:**

1. I would like to cert/keys to last for X years (long time)
2. I would like them to be valid for the entire domain *.company.com (I dont care for the internals just for the admin key for kubectl)
3. I would like to repeat the process 2 times (once for production, and once for QA/Staging) and eventually have 2 sets of credentials
4. override the default credentials and use `kube-aws up --export` to get the `userdata` i need for my cluster

**My problems are:**

1. how to make the admin cert valid for *.company.com
2. In the documentation they say that you need to create a `key-pair` for each node in the cluster... WHAT! `kube-aws render` generates only 1 worker `key-pair` so whats up with that!

Well now for the "fun" part:

> ```
> $ openssl genrsa -out ca-key.pem 2048
> $ openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca-key.pem -days 10000 -out ca.pem -subj "/CN=kube-ca"
> ```

I guess that the `-days 10000` solves my first problem with the expiration. cool

**API-SERVER key pair**

openssl.cnf

> ```
>   [req]
>     req_extensions = v3_req
>     distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
>     [req_distinguished_name]
>     [ v3_req ]
>     basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
>     keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
>     subjectAltName = @alt_names
>     [alt_names]
>     DNS.1 = kubernetes
>     DNS.2 = kubernetes.default
>     DNS.3 = kubernetes.default.svc
>     DNS.4 = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
>     is it
>     DNS.5 = mycompany.com
>     or
>     DNS.5 = *.mycompany.com
>     IP.1 = 10.3.0.1
>     IP.2 = 10.0.0.50
> ```

and run the commands

> ```
> $ openssl genrsa -out apiserver-key.pem 2048
> $ openssl req -new -key apiserver-key.pem -out apiserver.csr -subj "/CN=kube-apiserver" -config openssl.cnf
> $ openssl x509 -req -in apiserver.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out apiserver.pem -days 3650 -extensions v3_req -extfile openssl.cnf
> ```

Fine, besides the `subjectAltName` which I don't know how to use i could have made a few attempts to see what works its cool.

**Worker Keypairs**

Here is where I am really stuck, what am I supposed to do with this sentence:

```
This procedure generates a unique TLS certificate for every Kubernetes worker node in your cluster
```

Fine security and all but this is really unrealistic and overkill IMO on an amazon autoscaling group

So in case I don't want to have a key for each node but 1 key for all, how does my `worker-openssl.cnf` should look????

> ```
> [req]
> req_extensions = v3_req
> distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
> [req_distinguished_name]
> [ v3_req ]
> basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
> keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
> subjectAltName = @alt_names
> [alt_names]
> IP.1 = $ENV::WORKER_IP <- what am i supposed to do here?
> ```

after this creating the admin key pair is straight forward.

please help!

Comment: Exact same question here. Let me know if you find the answer outside SO please!

Comment: Yes i have i will post a solution today

Comment: Any luck finding a solution @Gleeb?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with this `worker-openssl.conf` using the **the same certificate** for all workers. Probably not the most secure setup.

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = *.*.cluster.internal
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should have *.mycompany.com in your alt-names. Or you can specify all possible variants like in this [manual](https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/generating-and-installing-wildcard-and-multi-domain-ssl-certificates)

Since you're running CoreOS you just need to configure cloud-config to generate your keys. You don't need to generate it manually for each node, and autoscalling should work fine.

I didn't do this on amazon, but I did deploy kubernetes manually on baremetal with all ssh keys and config. You can check out my blog post about it [here](http://blog.lwolf.org/post/migrate-infrastructure-to-kubernetes-building-baremetal-cluster/). Hopefully it will help a bit.